# Convert JSON ListView to Fragment

Tags: java, android

So I'm new to Java and I created a Listing Activity that fetches from MySQL/PHP. Right now I'm trying to get that activity into a Fragment for the Bottom Navigation drawer but it's not working. Here are the codes:

Fragment Code:

```
public class homeFragment extends Fragment {



public homeFragment(){



}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, null);
}
```

}

Code for the working List Activity

```
public class AllQnsActivity extends ListActivity {







//Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//Creating Json parser object
JSONParser jParser= new JSONParser ();

ArrayList <HashMap<String, String>> qnsList;

//URL to get all qns

private static String url_all_questions = "https:xyz.com/mysqlphpcode.php";

//JSON node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_QUESTIONS = "questions";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_QUESTION = "qn";
private static final String TAG_ASKER = "asker";
private static final String TAG_ANSWER = "answer";
private static final String TAG_STATUS = "";


//Questions JSON Array
JSONArray questions = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_qns);









    //HashMap for Listview
    qnsList = new ArrayList<HashMap <String, String>>();

    //Loading questions in background thread

    new LoadAllQns().execute();

    //get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single qn
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String qid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditQnActivity.class);
            // sending qid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, qid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }

    });
}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllQns extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllQnsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Questions. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All questions from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_questions, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("All Questions: ", json.toString());


        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // questions found
                // Getting Array of Questions
                questions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTIONS);

                // looping through All Questions
                for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = questions.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String question = c.getString(TAG_QUESTION);
                    String asker = c.getString(TAG_ASKER);
                    String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSWER);




                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_QUESTION, question);
                    map.put(TAG_ASKER, asker);
                    map.put(TAG_ANSWER, answer);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    qnsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no questions found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewQnActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all questions
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */


                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllQnsActivity.this, qnsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                        TAG_ASKER, TAG_QUESTION, TAG_ANSWER},
                        new int[] {R.id.id, R.id.asker, R.id.qn, R.id.answer });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

So now I want to this last piece of code to be a fragment (or more plainly, embed it) in the home tab (homeFragment).

Comment: Hmm, never personally worked with a ListActivity before, but I have worked with a normal ListView (which also uses an adapter). If I understand correctly, you want to display a list of items? setting the adapter should do that, make sure your list_item layout is correct. Else, you might want to use a normal activity with a fragment inside of it (so modify your activities layout). Not entirely sure what you want to do? And, I assume you have looked at this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity

Comment: @Zee Let me try that. Essentially here's what I'm trying to do: display a JSON list in the **Home ** tab of the bottom drawer menu. I had done this on an independent activity and it works fine but now I want to put it into a fragment

Comment: You can define the layout of a fragment the same way you do for an activity (in a .xml file). So, you can define a listview in the fragment and give it an adapter. You need to write your own adapter to display correctly, eg https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-and-viewholder/ 

Fragments tend to crash on orientation change if you are not careful! Look here to communicate back to activity using interfaces. Remember to use isAttached(): https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments